# Boss introduced my soon-to-be right hand via email. How to proceed now?

Tags: management, new-job, employer-relations, leadership

I recently accepted a new job and I'll be starting in a couple of weeks. The entire interview process has been online (video chat) because of Covid.

I'll be leading a team. Obviously, I have not met my team yet. I got an email from my manager CC'd one of my direct reports, just to introduce both of us over email. Email is very simple just says she is an excellent teammate (she will be my right hand) and will be strong support for me and to reach out to her if I have questions leading up to my start date etc.

How would you respond back to this? I want to make a good first impression on her since I'll be her new boss and also to my boss, but usually, I've done these in person haven't really been introduced like this over email.

Should I just pick up the phone and call the office and talk to her over the phone? Better than email? Or is that too much since I haven't officially started at the company yet?

Shouldn't my manager be introducing me in person on my first day? Hopefully, he will. I have a feeling maybe this employee applied for this job and did not get it. Do you think I should ask my manager and see if he has plans on introducing me in person and also if anyone internally has applied for this position?

Thanks!

Comment: The process has been by video chat/online due to Covid... but... will you have to go to the office once you start? A bit confused why the process was fully online and then you will have to physically go to the office... anyways, writing an answer.

Comment: Yes, I will be at the office on my start day in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Process is full online because you want to minimize interactions, not just because "you can". You can interview 100 persons in person as well, it takes the same time, if not less than online, but the covid19 risk would be significantly higher.

Answer (score 15):

Now that your Boss CC'd her, you now have knowledge/access to her email.

Thus, I suggest you **start by writing an email to her where you briefly introduce yourself**, etc., and then suggest that you **coordinate an online meeting with her** so you can further get acquainted.

This will help you to know her a bit, before you have the chance to actually meet her in person.

Yes, the phone call is also an option, but it's less effective than a video call (where you have audio *and* video, instead of just audio, as in the call).

Comment: I suggest to coordinate an *in-person* meeting with her, since OP has to physically visti the office, and the OP job did not start officially yet.

Comment: @EarlGrey yeah but OP want's to get more acquainted *before* actually starting and going to the office, so OP already knows her a bit more before actually having an in-person chat

Comment: I would avoid the in-person meeting until the official start day, I would agree with the video conference option, avoiding the in-person meeting has everything to do with the fact the actual start date hasn’t happened and literally nothing to do with the pandemic.

Answer (score 2):

You're wholly overthinking it.  You're senior to this person, so there is zero pressure.  Tap the reply button and type "Great to meet. See you on day one."  Indeed regardless of who is superior, tap the reply button and type "Great to meet. See you on day one."

It's that easy.

- Do nothing until the first day (other than a two-word hello). This is a duplicate that often comes up on this site
- For goodness sake, **say/ask nothing to your boss**. Your boss would find that bizarre
- Your worries about who applied for what are wholly irrelevant, forget all that and work on - on day one

Enjoy.

Comment: He is NOT the "senior".  SHE is the senior, he is the superior.  These are not the same and not interchangeable.  There's good reason to be humble to a senior when you're new, even if you rank higher.  Especially if they're you're right hand man because they know the political landscape and can trap you.

Comment: You seem agitated by this. It's completely normal to use senior as a comparative.  In any event, what the OP should do is what is stated here in the three points, and that's that.  (Whether the other party is the CEO, whatever.)

Comment: well, Jack was right!  I edited it already anyways.